# Obtain current date in attribute table

Tags: qgis, date

I'm having difficulties trying to set one function to get current date in one column on a shapefile's attribute table.

I know that using `now()` it does what I want, but that is static. If I check tomorrow the table, it will have today's date.

So, what I wanted is a function that whenever I open QGIS, it automatically updates the current date on the shapefile's attribute table.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You could create a virtual field - which then is only part of the attribute table in this specific project, but it does what you ask for.

Comment: Why would you do that if running now() at anytime gives you the actual current date and time?

Comment: Erik, could you please elaborate more? You are saying me to add a "virtual field" on the attribute table?